# Attach a txt file in Python smtplib

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am sending a plain text email as follows:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

def send_message():
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.sendgrid.net', 587)
    s.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)

    toEmail, fromEmail = to@email.com, from@email.com
    msg['Subject'] = 'subject'
    msg['From'] = fromEmail
    body = 'This is the message'

    content = MIMEText(body, 'plain')
    msg.attach(content)
    s.sendmail(fromEmail, toEmail, msg.as_string())
```

In addition to this message, I would like to attach a txt file, 'log_file.txt'. How would I attach a txt file here?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The same way, using `msg.attach`:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

filename = "text.txt"
f = file(filename)
attachment = MIMEText(f.read())
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)           
msg.attach(attachment)
```

Comment: As a side note, I had to attach the content *after* the attachment or it the plain text in the body wasn't showing.

Comment: email.mime.text works for me but  email.MIMEText not

Answer (score 22):

Since Python3.6, I would recommend start using EmailMessage instead of MimeMultipart. Fewer imports, fewer lines, no need to put the recipients both to the message headers and to the SMTP sender function parameter.

```py
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage

msg = EmailMessage()
msg["From"] = FROM_EMAIL
msg["Subject"] = "Subject"
msg["To"] = TO_EMAIL
msg.set_content("This is the message body")
msg.add_attachment(open(filename, "r").read(), filename="log_file.txt")

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.sendgrid.net', 587)
s.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
s.send_message(msg)
```

Even better is to install library [envelope](https://github.com/CZ-NIC/envelope/) by `pip3 install envelope` that's aim is to handle many things in a very intuitive manner:

```py
from envelope import Envelope
from pathlib import Path

Envelope()\
    .from_(FROM_EMAIL)\
    .subject("Subject")\
    .to("to")\
    .message("message")\
    .attach(Path(filename))\
    .smtp("smtp.sendgrid.net", 587, USERNAME, PASSWORD)\
    .send()
```

Comment: msg.add_attachment(open('log_file.txt', "r", encoding="utf8").read())
to avoid decode error for box / table chars.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me

```
sender = 'spider@fromdomain.com'
receivers = 'who'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'subject'
msg['From'] = 'spider man'
msg['To'] = 'who@gmail.com'
file='myfile.xls'

msg.attach(MIMEText("Labour"))
attachment = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
attachment.set_payload(open(file, 'rb').read())
encoders.encode_base64(attachment)
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="%s"' % os.path.basename(file))
msg.attach(attachment)

print('Send email.')
conn.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())
conn.close()
```