# Python: What is the correct MIME type for attaching html file to email

Tags: python, html, email, smtp

I've got a script that sends emails with html content in them.. works as expected... 
I'm having trouble sending an attachment with the email.

The attachment is an html file stored in the active directory of the script... "test.html"

How do I attach the html file to the email? I've tried snippets from various other posts I've found relating to this, but each returned the same output of "no such file or directory".

code as follows:

```
import smtplib
import os
import email.encoders
import email.mime.text
import email.mime.base
import mimetools
import base64



from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

    # me == Outgoing email address
    # you == Recipient's email address
me = "secret"
you = "secret"

    # Create message container - the correct MIME type is multipart/alternative.
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
msg['Subject'] = "TEST"
msg['From'] = me
msg['To'] = you
emailMsg = email.MIMEMultipart.MIMEMultipart('alternative')

    # Create the body of the message (a plain-text and an HTML version).
html = """\
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>test</p>
</body>
</html>"""


    # Record the MIME types of both parts - text/plain and text/html.
part1 = MIMEText(text, 'plain')
part2 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
filename = "C:/CHRIS/ServerStatus/Oceaneering_Server_Status.html"
f = file(filename)
attachment = MIMEText(f.read(), _subtype='html')
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)

    # Attach parts into message container.
    # According to RFC 2046, the last part of a multipart message, in this case
    # the HTML message, is best and preferred.
msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)
msg.attach(attachment)

    # Send the message via local SMTP server.
mail = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

mail.ehlo()

    # mail.login(username, password) to Outgoing email account
mail.login('secret', 'secret')
mail.sendmail(me, you, msg.as_string())
mail.quit()
```

i've updated my code in hopes to get this question back on topic... i've made a little progress with the help of Dirk and this link:
[Attach a txt file in Python smtplib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541837/attach-a-txt-file-in-python-smtplib)...

I've been able to physically send an attachment now, but the attachment is still coming through as a text type of file of sort and does not open as the original html file does.

So to reword my question... What is the corrective action for changing the MIME type of this code to correctly attach an .html file to an html based email?

The relative path and directory of my py script and the html file needed to be sent is as follows:
C:\CHRIS\ServerStatus\

This is the output i'm receiving with the code I have:
[image]

This is the way the html doc looks outside of the email script (The way it's supposed to look):
[image]

Comment: This code works for me on Linux, with some random html file, receiving the mail in gmail, so I'm afraid I'm not seeing your problem... It might be related to the charset, file encoding or the mail client you are using.
Official docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html#id2 Note: have you looked at installing envelopes and using the code below? This should take care of the nitty gritty details, cross platform issues etc.

Comment: Thanks dirk,

I've played with the envelopes module, but I couldn't get it to work correctly. I'm ultimately switching this code over to operate on smtp 25 with no ssl and running on a server we have, but for testing purposes i have it structured with gmail 587.. There's a bit more to this entire code outside of this scope, and i have a feeling it would require me to make quite a bit of changes

i've played with the charset and encoding, but still no luck.. I updated the original post with images to reflect the html doc.

Comment: Dirk,

When I replicate your code using the envelope module, I get an error of "Slice object has not attribute lower"..?

Comment: the "slice..." error is probably something with the strings you're passing in for the path or email address or something. a stack trace would help...

Comment: But, looking at the screenshots, the real culprit is most likely not the Python code, but your understanding how html files work... From what you're showing, the html file is looking ok, except that it is missing styling (and probably functionality). I would bet this is because certain css and/or javascript files that are referenced in the original are not available for the email copy. You could solve this by including any desirable markup/styling inline in the html, but you will need to change the file: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/adding-css-to-html-with-link-embed-inline-and-import.

Comment: Dirk, I believe it is inline. The styling rules are in the header of the html.

Comment: So apparently I goofed...

The script above works. The issue lies in how the gmail client renders the preview of the html doc. If downloaded, the html document appears as it should.

Answer (score 2):

I would encourage you to use a library rather than deal with the -rather unpythonic- built-in mail modules, such as the highly recommended envelopes:

https://tomekwojcik.github.io/envelopes/index.html

install with:

```
pip install envelopes
```

Python code:

```
import os
from envelopes import Envelope

filename = "C:/CHRIS/ServerStatus/Oceaneering_Server_Status.html"

envelope = Envelope(
    from_addr=(me),
    to_addr=(you),
    subject=u'Test',
    text_body=u'Plain text version',
    html_body=html
)
envelope.add_attachment(filename)

envelope.send('smtp.gmail.com', login='secret', password='secret', tls=True)
```

Comment: Sorry, about that..

the directory of the html file is "C:\CHRIS\ServerStatus\Server_Status.html"..
The directory of the python script generating the email is "C:\CHRIS\ServerStatus\ServerStatus.py"..

I'm able to send the email out, but I just wasn't able to physically attach the .html file to the email.

Comment: I added these lines in and it made the attachment... however, the attachment appears to be sent in a text format rather than the original html file?

filename = "C:/CHRIS/ServerStatusServer_Status.html"
f = file(filename)
attachment = MIMEText(f.read())
attachment.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
msg.attach(attachment)

Comment: MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype='html') is probably the answer you are looking for, but I have to agree that this makes the question kinda off-topic unless it is rephrased. First because this answer is actually not a good fit for the original question and second because it is not a useful addition to SO (people with your problem will not find this question and people who find the question are not likely to have your problem :-))

Comment: Thanks, I've reworded the question and post. Hopefully thats back on topic? 

That change that you recommended did not output what i was looking for however.. :(